# hiding of scheduled execution of powershell script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I scheduled execution of *.ps1 script in Windows 7 scheduler.
Everything is cool but i need it to execute silently (not showing PowerShell window every time)

Answer (score 4):

use PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden